# I am working on a web app using Django, running on Nginx, and I am getting 111 connection refused, and I cant work out why

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx

I have previously configured an app in the exact same way but when I updated Ubuntu, I broke my python install. I fixed python, and tried to set up another app in the exact same way, using the same tutorials, but I am getting a 111 error when I try to connect. I can connect if I run the app using gunicorn (which I only tried because it wasn't working using nginx), but I want to find the problem and fix it. As far as I can see everything is configured according to the documentation I went through.

Here is the uwsgi config file

```
# glossbox_uwsgi.ini file

[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /usr/local/apps/glossbox/glossbox
# Django's wsgi file
wsgi-file = /usr/local/apps/glossbox/glossbox/glossbox/wsgi.py
# the virtualenv (full path)
home            = /usr/local/apps/glossbox/venv
plugins = python
# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 10
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = server 127.0.0.1:8001
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket    = 664
clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
```

here is the nginx conf file:

```
# glossbox_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name vps746196.ovh.net; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /usr/local/apps/glossbox/glossbox/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /usr/local/apps/glossbox/glossbox/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /usr/local/apps/glossbox/glossbox/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

the app runs using the command 'uwsgi --ini glossbox_uwsgi.ini' but I get 111 connection refused when I try to connect.

I tried to run using 'gunicorn glossbox.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000' just to see if it worked, and it did, although site couldn't find the static files for the admin site, I assume that is down to me having no configuration set up for gunicorn. Either way, I need to find out why it is refusing the connection.

Any help will be appreciated :-)

Comment: `8000 != 8001`.

Comment: You're right there, I just copied and pasted the gunicorn command which was using port 8000 instead of 8001. using 'gunicorn glossbox.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000' ignores all my config files which are set at 8001. If i try to run using 'uwsgi --ini glossbox_uwsgi.ini' or 'uwsgi --socket :8001 --wsgi-file glossbox/wsgi.py', I get have the same issue regardless of the ports I use.